# /etc/systemd/logind.conf is being ignored

Tags: linux, debian

I would like to have the closing of my laptop lid ignored on a Debian 10 machine I have. The laptop is a 2017 Macbook Air.

Many guides online say that `HandleLidSwitch` and `HandleLidSwitchExternalPower`, and `HandleLidSwitchDocked` must be set to ignore.

These lines come straight from /etc/systemd/logind.conf to show that I have done this:

```
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HndleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
```

I then run `systemctl restart systemd-logind` as root but the problem persists.

Even after rebooting my computer I get the same problem.

Interestingly it seems that the file is not being parsed correctly as shown by the output of this command:

```
nick@debserver:~$ busctl get-property org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager HandleLidSwitch
s "suspend"
```

I am not sure what I need to do.

Comment: I know nothing about `logind.conf`, except what I have just read in the [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html), and I haven't even read the whole of it. But it states about the precedence: "entries in a file in any configuration directory override entries in the single configuration file". Please check if there are entries that override.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to mention here initially based on quick research and observation, I want to itemized some items of interest that may help:

1. It seems you have a typo in your config file as `HndleLidSwitch=ignore` where it should be `HandleLidSwitch=ignore`.

   - This is likely the issue with that parameter not being parsed correctly so I'd start by getting this corrected first in case it's as simple as that.
2. Furthermore, as per [logind.conf, logind.conf.d — Login manager configuration files](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html) as few key things to note that I read:

   > - Only input devices with the "power-switch" udev tag will be watched for key/lid switch events.
   > - If the system is inserted in a docking station, or if more than one display is connected, the action specified by `HandleLidSwitchDocked=`
   >   occurs; if the system is on external power the action (if any)
   >   specified by `HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=` occurs; otherwise the
   >   `HandleLidSwitch=` action occurs.
   > - A different application **may disable logind's handling of system power and sleep keys and the lid switch** by taking a low-level inhibitor lock ("handle-power-key", "handle-suspend-key", "handle-hibernate-key", "handle-lid-switch", "handle-reboot-switch").
   >
   >   - This is **most commonly used by graphical desktop environments to take over suspend and hibernation handling, and to use their own configuration mechanisms.** If a low-level inhibitor lock is taken, logind will not take any action when that key or switch is triggered and the Handle*= settings are irrelevant.
3. Additionally according to a comment on the [HandleLidSwitch in /etc/systemd/logind.conf is ignored](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/11638) post:

   > This might help someone. I was having the same issue because
   > `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` was a symlink. After copying the original
   > file instead of symlinking it `logind.conf` isn't ignored anymore

Comment: Nicholas.... You might also try as suggest in [this GitHub issue post](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7137) and "*Log with `systemd.log_level=debug` set in boot parameters*" and see if the log indicates that the handle-lid-switch is inhibited or not to help further troubleshoot. Happy to do more research but this is where I'd start with in case these points mentioned in my answer helps.

Comment: ...it was the typo. In 4 hours I can award the bounty.